# How to make two versions of a web site?

Tags: html, css, web

I have an HTML page with, for example, a data-changing form, and I want it to be visible for authenticated user, and not visible for unauthenticated visitors.

Is it possible to have something like this in HTML or CSS? I've read about something like a "**readonly**" attribute, but it's not what I'm looking for. Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: You'd want to use PHP (Secure) or Javascript(Lite, unsecure) to do something like this.  How do you plan to "authenticate"?

Comment: This will almost certainly require some sort of backend code. If you want it to be super-simply (unreliable and insecure), you could possibly do it by setting a cookie. Either way, you'll have to be writing some code, whether it be JavaScript, PHP, Ruby, etc

Comment: The point is that I have no idea what I can use. As i just said I tried readonly but it doesn't seem to fully resolve my problem cause It's not only about forms but also some other HTML code what I'm trying to hide.

Comment: Use Wordpress, there are multiple ways to accomplish this that way.

Comment: That function is a server side solution which CMSs have a plug in for if you don't role your own.

Comment: I've got a server in backend handling authentications and sessions. I can write some backend code or saome JS script but I don't know how to do it in HTML to hide something.

Comment: That would be done on the backend level using a boolean to check if you are authenticated. If not, do not output the HTML chunk you are hiding. The HTML itself does nothing for you in this case, it is either there or it isn't.

Comment: @Michael You should post that as an answer (possible with a snippet of code w/ the basics of a boolean check)

Comment: Ok. I'm aware of that, taht I have to do it on the backend level by checking authentication status. But the thing I do not know is how to not output the HTML chunk I want to hide. I do not know if you understand my problem.

Comment: @kuba12 what server side language are you using? node.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it possible to have something like this in HTML or CSS?"

No, or rather it is not recommended to simply hide a form using CSS. That is not secure. If a person really wanted to they could unhide it and submit the form.

You should hide it on the backend level so that the HTML markup isn't even generated on the frontend. The exact implementation for this varies across platforms, but the concept is basically the same. Here is a PHP example:

PHTML - page.phtml (view template file)

```
<? if($user.is_authenticated) : ?>

    <form action="edit-database.php">
      <label for="sku">SKU</label>
      <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

<? end ?>
```